# Efficiently creating additional columns in a pandas DataFrame using .map()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing a data set that is similar in shape to the following example. I have two different types of data (*abc* data and *xyz* data):

```
   abc1  abc2  abc3  xyz1  xyz2  xyz3
0     1     2     2     2     1     2
1     2     1     1     2     1     1
2     2     2     1     2     2     2
3     1     2     1     1     1     1
4     1     1     2     1     2     1
```

I want to create a function that adds a categorizing column for each *abc* column that exists in the dataframe. Using lists of column names and a category mapping dictionary, I was able to get my desired result.

```
abc_columns = ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3']
xyz_columns = ['xyz1', 'xyz2', 'xyz3']
abc_category_columns = ['abc1_category', 'abc2_category', 'abc3_category']
categories = {1: 'Good', 2: 'Bad', 3: 'Ugly'}

for i in range(len(abc_category_columns)):
    df3[abc_category_columns[i]] = df3[abc_columns[i]].map(categories)

print df3
```

The end result:

```
   abc1  abc2  abc3  xyz1  xyz2  xyz3 abc1_category abc2_category abc3_category
0     1     2     2     2     1     2          Good           Bad           Bad
1     2     1     1     2     1     1           Bad          Good          Good
2     2     2     1     2     2     2           Bad           Bad          Good
3     1     2     1     1     1     1          Good           Bad          Good
4     1     1     2     1     2     1          Good          Good           Bad
```

While the `for` loop at the end works fine, I feel like I should be using Python's `lambda` function, but can't seem to figure it out.

Is there a more efficient way to map in a dynamic number of *abc*-type columns?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with the dictionary [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
In [11]: df[abc_columns].applymap(categories.get)
Out[11]:
   abc1  abc2  abc3
0  Good   Bad   Bad
1   Bad  Good  Good
2   Bad   Bad  Good
3  Good   Bad  Good
4  Good  Good   Bad
```

And put this to the specified columns:

```
In [12]: abc_categories = map(lambda x: x + '_category', abc_columns)

In [13]: abc_categories
Out[13]: ['abc1_category', 'abc2_category', 'abc3_category']

In [14]: df[abc_categories] = df[abc_columns].applymap(categories.get)
```

Note: you can construct `abc_columns` relatively efficiently using a list comprehension:

```
abc_columns = [col for col in df.columns if str(col).startswith('abc')]
```

Comment: @AndyHayden, what is the difference between .applymap on a dataframe and .map on a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @yoshiserry applymap does it to each cell, rather than each row/col.

Comment: @AndyHayden I'm not sure what you mean, so ApplyMap applies the function to every cell (being every intersection of row and column) so basically across the entire dataframe. Whereas .map just does it for a single row or a single column?

Comment: @yoshiserry yup.  (and .apply is basically the same as .map but you'll see it used more often.)